# CentOS 7 - problem encountered with the set up of spec file during creation of RPM package

Tags: centos, packaging, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, alien

I'm aiming to translate a Debian package to an RPM package to install it on a CentOS Linux 7 (Red Hat).
I used alien to accomplish it: `alien --to-rpm --scripts --keep-version --generate debian_pkg.deb`. I use the `--generate` flag to create a directory for building a package from, because I want to add the runtime dependencies to the spec file. To do so, I add this line: `Requires: nodejs tomcat8 java-1.8.0-openjdk java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`. Then I try to create the package: `rpmbuild -ba <package_name>.spec`, but it ends abruptly with this error:

```
Processing files: <package_name>
error: Directory not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/<package_name>/srv
error: Directory not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/<package_name>/srv/tmp
error: File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/<package_name>/srv/tmp/file.tar.gz
error: File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/<package_name>/usr/share/doc/frontend/README.Debian
error: File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/<package_name>/usr/share/doc/frontend/changelog.Debian.gz
error: File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/<package_name>/usr/share/doc/frontend/copyright


RPM build errors:
    Directory not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/<package_name>/srv
    Directory not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/<package_name>/srv/tmp
    File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/<package_name>/srv/tmp/file.tar.gz
    File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/<package_name>/usr/share/doc/frontend/README.Debian
    File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/<package_name>/usr/share/doc/frontend/changelog.Debian.gz
    File not found: /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/<package_name>/usr/share/doc/frontend/copyright
```

I searched the internet and found that it's linked to the `%install` section and more specifically `%{buildroot}`, but I can't get my head around the problem and fix it. Can somebody give me a hand?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is the spec file in essence:

```
Buildroot: /home/<package_dir>
Version: 1.0
Release: 849
Distribution: Debian
Group: Converted/misc
Requires: nodejs tomcat8 java-1.8.0-openjdk java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel

%define _rpmdir ../
%define _rpmfilename %%{NAME}-%%{VERSION}-%%{RELEASE}.%%{ARCH}.rpm
%define _unpackaged_files_terminate_build 0

%pre
# some shell script

%post
# some shell script

%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/usr/share/doc/
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/usr/share/doc/frontend/

%files
%dir "/srv/"
%dir "/srv/tmp/"
"/srv/tmp/file.tar.gz"
%dir "/usr/"
%dir "/usr/share/"
%dir "/usr/share/doc/"
%dir "/usr/share/doc/frontend/"
"/usr/share/doc/frontend/README.Debian"
"/usr/share/doc/frontend/changelog.Debian.gz"
"/usr/share/doc/frontend/copyright"
```

Comment: It's hard to debug this without more context... Can you post more from the spec file? What about the build logs leading to.that point?

Comment: @filbranden thanks for your reply. I've updated the post with a summary of the spec file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The problem you're having is with the `Buildroot:` tag in the specfile.

In modern systems (and perhaps yours included), `Buildroot:` in a spec file is no longer supported and it's now ignored.

See [this post on LinuxQuestions](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/rpmbuild-picking-up-default-buildroot-even-after-explicitily-defining-in-spec-file-945144/) about that:

> Fedora (as of F-10) does not require the presence of the BuildRoot tag in the spec and if one is defined it will be ignored.

You can work around this by passing rpmbuild a `--buildroot` argument so it uses `/home/<package_dir>`. (It's possible this might have adverse side effects such as removing those contents after the build is done, which apparently is also the default now.)

In fact, passing rpmbuild and explicit `--buildroot` is what `alien` started doing since rpm 4.7.0 started ignoring `Buildroot:`, as you can see in [this commit](https://github.com/mildred/alien/commit/9c28b11e6c996ff0e72c682afcee3dd6023e3121).

---

The specfile isn't really installing any sources or creating any files.

The only thing happening in the `%install` section is creating an (empty) `/usr/share/doc/frontend/` directory.

Since the specfile starts by specifying `Buildroot: /home/<package_dir>`, I imagine it expected that directory to be previously populated, so that the rpmbuild step would be able to simply pick up the already staged contents from there and just package them.

If you run `alien` again from the same .deb (in other words, start over), do you get a `/home/<package_dir>` that is populated with e.g. `srv/tmp/file.tar.gz`? If so, rpmbuild will work when you run it at that point.

It is possible some macro in your rpmbuild is cleaning `%{buildroot}` after building the rpm (though I'd say that's unusual, since typically that requires a `%clean` section in your specfile.) Check whether that's the case, if right after a first (successful) rpmbuild, the files under `/home/<package_dir>` are gone, in which case further runs of rpmbuild will fail as you describe...

Comment: Yes, when running `alien` I get two directories besides the spec file; `srv/tmp/`, which contains `file.tar.gz` and `usr/share/doc/dblab-frontend/` which contains `README.Debian`, `copyright` and `changelog.Debian.gz`.

Comment: Ah! So it seems there's a disconnect between `/root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/<package_name>` and `/home/<package_dir>` specified as Buildroot:! Have you tried to use `rpmbuild` (and alien) as a non-root user?

Comment: I've just tried to run `rpmbuild` as a non-root user, but it gives the same errors as before. Should I specify another `Buildroot` maybe?

Comment: If you pass `rpmbuild` a `--buildroot /home/<package_dir>` explicitly, does that work? Or do you still get the `/root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT` paths?

Comment: I've eventually managed to make it work. What I did is to add this under the `%install` section:

`mkdir -p %{buildroot}/srv/tmp/`
`mkdir -p %{buildroot}/usr/share/doc/frontend/`
`install -m 0755 /home/frontend-1.0/srv/tmp/file.tar.gz  %{buildroot}/srv/tmp/file.tar.gz`
`install -m 0755 /home/frontend-1.0/.../frontend/README.Debian %{buildroot}/.../frontend/README.Debian`
`install -m 0755 /home/frontend-1.0/.../changelog.Debian.gz %{buildroot}/.../changelog.Debian.gz`
`install -m 0755 /home/frontend-1.0/.../frontend/copyright %{buildroot}/.../frontend/copyright`

Comment: I updated my answer. I just looked at source code of `alien` and confirmed it will call `rpmbuild` passing it a `--buildroot`, so that should work.

Comment: See [this commit](https://github.com/mildred/alien/commit/9c28b11e6c996ff0e72c682afcee3dd6023e3121) for the fix to `alien` for recent versions of rpm.

Comment: I guess, in short: don't use `alien`! It's unfortunately mostly bitrotten at this point... You're probably better off building an RPM specfile from scratch...

Comment: Thanks for your time @filbranden. I appreciate it :)